# How to save Japanese characters into Mysql by java spring and hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

I have several files raw data save as .DAT, this file have Japanese characters.
I want to save Japanese characters into database by java spring boot.
I am using :

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Intellij
- Hiibernate
- Spring boot
- Gradle

Setup database:

```
url: jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/msf?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Read file and save into database:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sources.data/DATADEMO");

    if (file.exists()){
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getPath()))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] str = line.split(",");
                MsPaymentSake msPaymentSake = new MsPaymentSake();
                msPaymentSake.setStoreCode(str[0]);
                msPaymentSake.setType(str[1]);
                msPaymentSake.setClassification(str[2]);
                msPaymentSake.setCapacity(str[3]);
                msPaymentSake.setStatsDate(str[4]);
                msPaymentSake.setPartner(str[5].trim());
                msPaymentSake.setProductName(str[6].trim());
                msPaymentSake.setFrequencyAll(str[7]);
                msPaymentSake.setQuantity(str[8]);
                msPaymentSake.setPrice(str[9]);
                msPaymentSake.setTotalPrice(str[10]);
                msPaymentSake.setFrequency(str[11]);
                msPaymentSake.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
                paymentSakeRepository.save(msPaymentSake);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
        file.delete();
    } else{
        System.out.println("can't find file!");
    }
```

Comment: What is your problem? You can already do so by setting encoding to utf8.

Comment: Yes, I know, but when I setting for file "DATADEMO" to utf8, the result still don't change!

Comment: What do you mean by won't change? Is there an error, or what exactly is the actual result?

Comment: this is result : "��Ĺݺ���(�"

Comment: Is the charset for your database, table and column utf8? MySQL default is latin1.

Comment: I know, I'm adjusting them to Utf-8.

Comment: What has the SQL connection string to to with your example code where you are "just" reading a file?

Comment: @Mick How can i read it or convert the string to Japanese?

Comment: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`

Comment: I think the above code will solve your issue UTF-8 with BufferedReader

Comment: when I save it to database so the result is "��Ĺݺ���(�"

Comment: You must decode then encode the string for each filed which may appears Japanese characters. And what kind of encoding should be used bases on the database.

Comment: The simplest (and cleanest) solution is to require the use of UTF-8 everywhere. Then you don't need any conversions at all. Plus, you never mentioned whether the file you are reading is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: @SOFe, about the case, we can't use `UTF-8`, we have to use `Shift_JIS`

Comment: Then you should have converted it while parsing bytes into a string.

Answer (score 2):

Use these in your application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.useUnicode=true
spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: So sad, I added it, so it doesn't produce the result I want

Comment: when you print msPaymentSake object, does it show the correct unicode string?

Comment: yes, I found solution for the issue `BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "Shift_JIS"))`